# How to parse quoted as well as unquoted arguments in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line

I want my perl script to correctly parse two command line arguments separated by a space into two variables:

```
$ cat 1.pl
print "arg1 = >$ARGV[0]<\n";
print "arg2 = >$ARGV[1]<\n";
$ perl 1.pl a b
arg1 = >a<
arg2 = >b<
$ perl 1.pl "a b"
arg1 = >a b<
arg2 = ><
$
```

Is there a generic way of dealing with this rather than trying to detect whether quotes were used or not?

Comment: You want http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long#Options_with_multiple_values, thus: `program --foo arg1 --foo arg2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The data is passed to Perl by the shell.

- `program a b` will send `a` and `b`
- `program 'a b'` will send `a b`
- `program "a b"` will send `a b`
- `program a\ b` will send `a b`

Perl has, AFAIK, no way of telling the difference between any of the last three.

You could `split` every argument on spaces, and that would get the effect you are describing … but it would mean working in a different way to every other application out there.

Comment: Exactly; if the user explicitly quoted the argument, it's *not* "two command line arguments", it's one. Treating it as two will make your users hate you.

Comment: So, I need to check if one argument was passed or two (the code expects two). If one argument was passed, I will split it into two, is that correct?

Comment: You could do. I would throw an error report to the user and display the usage information instead.

Comment: `die "Two arguments are required" unless @ARGV == 2`; BTW: finding out whether something is an argument or not, I cannot help but think of Monty Python http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teMlv3ripSM

Answer (score 1):

Quentin's answer is not quite right for Windows.

Meanwhile, if you want to parse switches, Getopt::Long is best for that. But if you have two non-switch arguments, you could try this brute-force method:

```
my @args = map { split ' ' } @ARGV;
die usage() unless @args == 2;
```

or this:

```
die usage() 
    unless (
    my ( $arg1, $arg2 )
        = @ARGV == 1 ? ( split ' ', $ARGV[0], 3 )
        : @ARGV == 2 ? @ARGV
        :              ()
    ) == 2
    ;
```

Here, `die usage()` is just an pseudo-code.